# Importing asyncio throws error

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.6, importerror, python-asyncio

In my terminal, I wanted to test something with asyncio. Here's what I did:

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
```

And this threw an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
tasks.__all__ +
AttributeError: module 'asyncio.tasks' has no attribute '__all__'
```

Why does it throw this error, and how can I fix it? (I checked in my python 3.5 interpreter the same way and got no error, so maybe the library got corrupted?)

I've run Python with the `-v` switch, the output produced after running `import asyncio` at the prompt is rather large, so it is available in [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/7f8b6b049908d7153a3cb207691113e4).

Comment: Show full Python version

Comment: python 3.6.2. I'll add that.

Comment: Try brew upgrade python3

Comment: That's.. unexpected. Looks like you perhaps have a local `asyncio.tasks` module shadowing the built-in version? Any chance you have a `asyncio` directory *without a `__init__.py` file in it*, but with a `tasks.py` file?

Comment: No, I definitely don't. @GregEremeev Doing so now.

Comment: Can you please tell us what `import sys` then `sys.modules['asyncio.tasks']` prints after you see that traceback?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'asyncio.tasks'`

Comment: @OldBunny2800: ah, the traceback caused the modules to be cleaned up again. Run Python with the `-v` switch (will get very noisy), then tell us what is printed after `import asyncio`, in the question.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JXq4DQqf

Comment: @OldBunny2800: that tells us two things: it's the standard location (so nothing is shadowing the standard library) and that the *bytecode is deemed stale*: *# bytecode is stale for 'asyncio.tasks'*. This means the file has changed on disk, *something* corrupted your installation.

Comment: So what is the correct response @MartijnPieters

Comment: I've moved your pastebin data to a github gist, because pastebin.org doesn't keep pasties all that long. I trust Github a little more.

Comment: Did you run `pip install asyncio`? That would shadow the standard library with the version intended for Python 3.3.

Comment: No, don't think I did. Martijn Pieters figured out the problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your local installation has been corrupted. From the `python -v` output you provided:

```
# bytecode is stale for 'asyncio.tasks'
# code object from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py
import 'asyncio.tasks' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104cf7860>
```

The *bytecode is stale* message means that `asyncio/tasks.py` file is *newer* than the accompanying `asyncio/__pycache__/tasks.cpython-36.pyc` file. This indicates that something has altered the `tasks.py` file, causing the contents to be different from what was shipped with your Python binary.

For comparison, the sibling module `asyncio.events` was loaded from the bytecode cache, which was provided by the Python installer at install time:

```
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/__pycache__/events.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'asyncio.events' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104ccf4e0>
```

The code object for that module was loaded from the `asyncio/__pycache__/events.cpython-36.pyc` file.

You could re-install Python from the [OS X installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/python-3.6.2-macosx10.6.pkg), but at this point I'd just grab the [newer 3.6.5 release](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/) instead.

You could also try to re-instate the original contents by downloading the [original source from the v3.6.2 tag](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py), but then you'll have to make sure the bytecode is regenerated (run `sudo python -m compileall /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py`) and you'll need to check for any other such changed files (try `find /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6 -name \*.py -newer /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/__init__.py`)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's a bug

Try to upgrade your Python via brew

```
brew upgrade python3
```

Currently, Python 3.6.5 is available and there is no such problem

Comment: I'm trying that now.

Comment: ...Error, python3 not installed? Then how did I have python in the first place?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Which error? Try brew doctor and after that brew upgrade python3

Comment: No, still `Error: python3 not installed`

Comment: @OldBunny2800 then brew install python3. You have default Python3 which is a part of your OS. brew will install additional Python to another directory, don't worry.

Comment: No, there is no such bug in Python 3.6.2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how do you know?

Comment: @GregEremeev: because I can trivially create a 3.6.2 build and verify. There is no such bug in the 3.6.2 release.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You even don't know his OS version and other details to be sure. Upgrade Python still could be the solution.

Comment: @GregEremeev: it's a packaged OS X release of Python 3.6.2, given the /Library/Frameworks paths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171396/discussion-between-greg-eremeev-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: @GregEremeev The brew installation failed because of conflicting files.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 it happens sometimes, you just need to figure out how to resolve conflicts.

Comment: Here's the full error. https://pastebin.com/qjb9Pnrm It seems I already have python installed there. But I thought Homebrew installs things in a seperate location?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 brew suggested solutions, choose second - brew link --overwrite python. It will change links.

Comment: I ended up installing through the 64-bit package on the website, but thanks for your help! +1

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Ok. But anyway, try to figure out how to use brew. It's a very helpful tool on a mac machine.

Comment: I do use brew often, just not for installing versions of Python. ;)